# Why, instead of being modified, is the data getting added as a new row?

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am using Peewee for Python and trying to update the name of an instance, but instead of updating the instance, it is getting added as a new one. What is wrong?

```
from peewee import *
from datetime import date
db=SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name=CharField()
    birthday=DateField()
    is_relative=BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database=db

class Pet(Model):
    owner=ForeignKeyField(Person,related_name='pets')
    name=CharField()
    animal_type=CharField()

    class Meta:
        database=db


db.connect()

db.create_tables([Person,Pet],safe=True)

uncle_bob=Person(name='Bob',birthday=date(1960,1,15),is_relative=True)
uncle_bob.save()

grandma = Person.create(name='Grandma', birthday=date(1935, 3, 1), is_relative=True)
herb = Person.create(name='Herb', birthday=date(1950, 5, 5), is_relative=False)
grandma.name='Grand Dadi'
grandma.save()
```

I am getting the following table:

```
1|Bob|1960-01-15|1
2|Grandma|1935-03-01|1
3|Herb|1950-05-05|0
4|Bob|1960-01-15|1
5|Grand Dadi|1935-03-01|1
6|Herb|1950-05-05|0
```

Comment: It could be because the `grandma` instance's primary key isn't set. As stated in [the docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.save), saving an instance that doesn't have a primary key will cause and INSERT instead of an UPDATE.

Comment: Actually, I ran your code and it worked. Maybe you ran the script multiple times with different values?

Comment: @Blurp yeah that maybe the case . Thank you for pointing that out .